# Entity Framework, Code First 3 classes identical properties

Tags: entity-framework-4

**Let us assume I have 3 types of Html classes that have identical primitives / navigation properties:**

1. public virtual string HtmlTagName {get; set;}
2. public virtual ICollection < Attribute >  Attributes {get; set;}

   etc., etc., etc.

The only difference between these 3 classes are:

1. One Html class can have a collection of Html Classes (Parent Html Class)
2. One class can be a child of an Html Class (Child Html Class)
3. One class is a standalone, ie. it is neither a parent nor a child html class of another html class (Single Html Class)

It appears to me, having 3 classes of identical properties, save whether it is a parent, child or single, makes no since (again, as much of the properties are identical).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, someone correct me if I am wrong:

```
public class HtmlElement : DelEntity
{
    // Primitives
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key
    public virtual long? ParentElementId { get; set; } // If it is a child

    //Navigation - Class
    [ForeignKey("ParentElementId")]
    public virtual HtmlElement ParentHtmlElement { get; set; }        

    //Navigation - Collections (if it is a parent)
    private ICollection<HtmlElement> _childElements;

    [InverseProperty("ParentHtmlElement")]
    public virtual ICollection<HtmlElement> ChildElements
    {
        get { return _childElements ?? (_childElements = new HashSet<HtmlElement>()); }
        set { _childElements = value; }
    }
```

}

Comment: Yes, unless there is a requirement that a Child can never turn into a parent etc. Then you need to use other patterns, e.g. inheritance.